# tableview text over ride with previous text

Tags: iphone

i am displaying array of data in a table view.

my code for that is like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell


    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0,0 , 100, 25);    
   itemNameLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame] autorelease];

    itemNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    itemNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    itemNameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGRect anotherLabelFrame = CGRectMake(120, 0, 100, 25);
    quantityLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anotherLabelFrame] autorelease];

    quantityLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    quantityLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    MyGroceryListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyGroceryListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Category *obj = (Category *)[appDelegate.itemsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    quantityLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",obj.quantity];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:itemNameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:quantityLabel];


    return cell;
}
```

how can i resolve this.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

i am giving text for  itemNameLabel is using array and for quantityLabel using class object.

so,when i scrolling table view the array names are override on other label,but quantity label is not overriding because it is from class.

i need to display itemNameLabel from array since it changes it value.

when i scroll table view my tableview is looking like this.[image: mytableview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should alloc all lable in this section

```
 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

and in the else part you should just Tag those labels and reuse after it but there is another short and sweet way 
if Application is not much resource consuming

change

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

to

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Height for each row using the function

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 100.0f;
}
```